# Eo. . .quo se ipsa magis

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, medieval-latin

How would I translate this sentence?

"Eo vero minus ex hoc loco quicquam efficitur, quod Ecclesia cum rogat "Converte me Domine," rogat ut Deus quo se ipsa magis ad Deum convertat castigationem immittere velit."

I have this:

But something lesser is effected from this place, which the Church when it asks, "Restore me Lord," it asks that God convert them greater and will to send castigation.

Comment: a: In late Latin *quod* introduces a sort of indirect speech. b: *Eo... minus* and *quo... magis* are correlative; the less *x* happens, the more *y.* *Locus*  here means the verse from Jeremiah at the top of the chapter. At least that's what I think so far.

Answer (score 1):

But all the less is anything accomplished from this place, because when the Church asks "Cause me to turn, O Lord," She [*i.e.* the Church] asks God to send his punishment, so that She herself all the more may return to God.